# List Comprehension With Sublists

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Suppose I have the following lists:

```
first_list = ['a', 'c', 't', 'k', 'p']
second_list = ['a', 'c']
```

And I want to check that `first_list` contains all items in `second_list`, the following list comprehension would return `True` since `a` and `c` are in `first_list`.

`all(i in first_list for i in second_list)`

However suppose `second_list` contains a sublist, for example:

```
first_list = ['a', 'c', 't', 'k', 'p']
second_list = ['a', ['s', 't'], 'p']
```

How can I check that `first_list` contains **all** the 'top tier' items, plus **any** of the 'second tier' (nested) items?

For example, since `first_list` contains `a`, `p`, and at least one item in the sublist (`t`), it should return `True`.

I imagine I could write a function to unpack any sublists, however I'm wondering if there is a simpler way of doing this via list comprehension?

Comment: why do you want to use a list comprehension?

Comment: **Note:** The strings may contain more than one character. I want the whole string in `second_list` to match the whole string in `first_list`, for example if `first_list` contains 'foo', and `second_list` contans 'f', this would not match since the 2 items did not match in their entirety. **Also note:** I am happy to explore options other than list comprehensions if this is not the best approach.

Comment: Often I find it handy to a utility function to handle one element, e.g. `[fn(e) for e in second_list]`, That `fn(e)` can then check whether `e` is a string or a list, and test accordingly.  In other words, use the list comprehension (or other loop) to simplify the problem by just one level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
first_list = ['a', 'c', 't', 'k', 'p']
second_list = ['a', ['s', 't'], 'p']
first_set = set(first_list)

def matches(e):
    return set(e) & first_set if type(e) == list else e in first_set

all(map(matches, second_list))
```

Why `set(e) & first_set`?

If we're comparing elements in two lists (or more generally, iterables), and don't care how many times each element appears, [sets](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) are a good bet, in part because of their operators such as difference `-` and intersection `&`. Here, we want to know if there's any commonality between the elements in a sublist, and the `first_list`. First, we convert them to sets. Commonality is represented by intersection, or `&`, which returns the common elements from both sets. So in this example, we have

```
{'s', 't'} & {'a', 'c', 't', 'k', 'p'} == {'t'}
```

I'm then using the fact that a non-empty set is truthy: `bool({}) is False`, `bool({'t'}) is True`.

(Note that `map` is lazily evaluated, so the expression will stop evaluating on the first element that doesn't match - i.e. it's just as efficient as a loop comprehension in that regard.)

Comment: Thank you! This did exactly what I needed. Do you mind please briefly explaining what the set logic is doing here.

Comment: Thanks so much the clear explanation, it was very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

First Unpack the second_list and then compare:

```
first_list = ['a', 'c', 't', 'k', 'p']
second_list = ['a', ['s', 't'], 'p']

second_list = [item for sublist in second_list for item in sublist]

common = [i for i in set(first_list) if i in set(second_list)]
print common
```

Output is ['a', 't', 'p']

Comment: this kind of unpacking won't work if string is more then once character, or there is number in list

Comment: This would work if I wanted **all** items in `second_list` to be included in `first_list`, and in this case ['a', 's', 't', 'p'] would return `False`. However what I instead want is at least one (but not necessarily all) of the items in any sublists to be included in `first_list`.

Answer (score 0):

If we could use the set, the problem may be solved efficiently.

```
first_list = ['a', 'c', 't', 'k', 'p']
second_list = ['a', ['s', 't'], 'p']

first_set = set(first_list)
second_set = [set(item) for item in second_list]

all(item & first_set for item in second_set)
```

Comment: This seems to work if all strings are a single character (which may not be the case). If any of the strings contain more than one character, they are broken up which is not what is intended.